# Simple elasticsearch query to get results by field value

Tags: elasticsearch

I belive the problem is described in the question itself. I'm making a simple query:

```
GET /base/products

"body": {
  "query": {
    "filtered": {
        "filter": {
          "and": {
            "filters": [
              {
                "match": {
                  "userId": "10"
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

But in the responses I get all the items from the database. Actually, I get that number of results provided in the `"size"` property.

I'm fairly new to **elasticsearch** so any help is very appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need term query, it matches exact value of a field:

```
{
  "query": {
    "term": {
      "userId": "10" 
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: In this case, `term` and `match` query does not make any difference.